# Android layout_gravity

Tags: android

I can't understand why the following code places my TextView in the top left corner of my screen.  Based on my understanding of layout_gravity, it seems that it should place my TextView at the bottom of my screen instead.

Can anyone please shed some light on this for me?  This Linear Layout, despite seeming very simplistic, has caused me numerous headaches.  How can something that seems so simple, be such a royal pain to grasp?

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="#FF0000">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/hello"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:background="#FFF"
            />    

    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

A LinearLayout set to vertical orientation will ignore all layout_gravity parameters that refers to vertical alignment. So for example "bottom" wont work but "center-horizontal" will work. (The vertical alignment is always done so that each view in the layout i placed under the  other views in the layout.)

A relative layout might be the way to go or maybe you can use this code that probably is pretty close to what you want.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#FF0000"
>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:background="#FFF" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**Edit** This [blog](http://sandipchitale.blogspot.se/2010/05/linearlayout-gravity-and-layoutgravity.html) explains things further.

Comment: @Justin Jenkins if it helped then you must mark it as resolved, this way people coming to your post will come to know that this was the most suitable answer to your question...

Comment: but but but he just stole my answer :-(

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#FF0000">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/hello"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="#FFF"
            />    

    </RelativeLayout>
```

you can use relative layout were you can align bottom easily

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  I was leaning towards using RelativeLayout for most of my 'actual' layouts.  I was using this example just because I wanted to fully understand LinearLayout before I moved on to the RelativeLayout.  It was just blowing my mind how something that seemed so simple at first, ended up being totally un-intuitive based on my understanding of the explanations in the docs.  I couldn't think of a more simplistic example than this, yet it was causing me lots of problems when it came to positioning the text the way I want.

Comment: if simply you want horizontal or vertical layout then use linear else would be better to use relative. ofcourse re;ative quite though then linear but once you understand it, it is much easier then linear

Answer (score 0):

I think this code do what you want:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:background="#FF0000">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello"
        android:background="#FFF"
        />    

</LinearLayout>
```

And if you want the textview on center, you can use:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:background="#FF0000">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="#FFF"
        />    

</LinearLayout>
```

Hope this help you.

Comment: what hapeens if he has more than one child view in linear layout all of then will be aligned at bottom or not?

Answer (score 0):

If that is the simplicity of your layout, you shouldn't wrap it in a LinearLayout at all.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:background="#FFF"
    android:text="HELLO HELLO" />
```

If you  need to wrap it though, remove the vertical orientation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#FF0000" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="#FFF"
        android:text="HELLO HELLO" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Why does removing the vertical orientation cause the layout_gravity to work the way I expect it to work?  Does the vertical orientation somehow alter the way layout_gravity functions?  It sure seems like it does.  I can't understand the logic behind this behavior, though.  I am sure there is a good reason for it, I'm just not seeing it right now.

Comment: Ooops...this was explained in the post just below this one.  Didn't quite make it there yet when I posted my first comment. :)

Comment: @JustinJenkins Because a vertical linear layout ignores bottom gravity as it is trying to stack the children 'vertically' any horizontal gravitys will work though