# I want to bring my relative layout in bottom

Tags: android, android-layout

what changes shall I make to bring the relative layout in bottom?

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="86dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_weight="0.08"
    android:gravity="bottom" >
   </RelativeLayout>
      </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Remove android:layout_weight="0.08", You didnot assign the weightsum to its parent Layout. And make the Parent RelativeLayout.

Comment: @rahulkapoor `weight_sum` isn't necessary when using `weight`...only in some situations

Comment: its still not helping.

Comment: @AmeerHumza Change the parent LinearLayout to RelativeLayout.

Comment: Did you try using `android:layout_gravity` instead of `gravity`?

Comment: Rahul changing parent worked out, thanks.

Comment: @AmeerHumza see my answer for an explanation as to *why* this isn't working. I will try to find a link soon that better explains it.

Comment: @AmeerHumza I have edited with a couple links and explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your parent Layout to be a `RelativeLayout`, since the attribute `android:layout_alignParentBottom` does nothing for `LinearLayout` children:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="86dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by using a `FrameLayout` instead of a `LinearLayout` since it stacks childs from top to bottom by default.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="86dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom" >
    </RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: frame layout also not helping :/

Comment: Check my edited answer. You need "layout_gravity" in order to do the trick.

Comment: What's the difference in using frame layout instead relative when using as a parent? @gian1200

Comment: The way you organize the children. For example layout_gravity="bottom" vs layout_alignParentBottom="true". The other thing may be the memory usage, but I haven't done that kind of tests in order to know which one is more efficient. But both approaches should work. It depends on the rest of your code. Some things are easier to make with FrameLayout rather than LinearLayout and viceversa.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <!-- replace this by any other layout or view. You might want something here, right? -->    
    <View android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="86dp">
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues here. The first being that

`android:gravity`

is wrong. This sets the `gravity` for the contents of this `View`s children. So for example used in a `TextView` it would place the `text` at the bottom if the `TextView`. What you want instead is

`android:layout_gravity`

this sets the `View`s `gravity` within its parent.

The second problem is that  `android:gravity="bottom"` doesn't work as you would expect in a `LinearLayout` who's `orientation` is `vertical`. I'm not sure I can explain why well so I will try to find a link in a bit that explains it. But if you change the `orientation` of the `LinearLayout` to `horizontal` you will see this.

So your best options are to change the `orientation` if that's a possibility and if not then change the root `ViewGroup` to a `RelativeLayout` and use the property `android:alignParentBottom="true"` as someone already suggested.

**Edit for explanation**

[This blog post](http://sandipchitale.blogspot.se/2010/05/linearlayout-gravity-and-layoutgravity.html) and [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10260766/android-layout-gravity), among others explain it a little. But basically, if the `orientation` is `horizontal` then the `View`s are layed out from left to right as we expect so you can't control the left and right `gravity`. With a `vertical orientation`, the same is true for top and bottom `gravity` because where they are placed vertically is already determined by Android when you set that `orientation`. I hope this makes sense.